# Trying to find an algorithm for matching edge images together

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, matching, edge-detection

I have 2 edge images and they are not same at scale and rotation, I need an algorithm that matches these edge images together. I saw in some papers it happened to match edge images with different scale and rotation, I send title of this paper here:

"An Integrated UAV Navigation System Based on Aerial
Image Matching"

Edge matching for images with difference scale and rotation:

[image]

A Sobel edge detector is applied to the images; in this work, image matching is performed by computing a correlation measurement (cross-correlation process)

Comment: Is there a question you want to ask? We are not going to write the code for you

Comment: Even I find it hard to match them..

Comment: Ander Biguri, i don't want write a code for me, i just wanna know that you know any library in python or matlab that do this work ? or maybe you had a code that do it from before, if you could send it for me

Comment: "Knowing any library" is off topic for this site (falling under recommendation of an off-site resource), as this sort of question tends to attract opinionated answers. Please read [ask]. "Send pre-existing code" is also off topic unless you have a well defined question (which this isn't), this isn't a free code writing service, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: What you're looking for is known as the registration problem. Have a look at 'image registration software' on google.